# std::future still valid after calling get() (which throws an exception)

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, stl, future

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get), after calling `std::future::get`:

> valid() is false after a call to this method.

Additionally, from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future/get/):

> Once the shared state is ready, the function unblocks and returns (or throws) releasing its shared state. This makes the future object no longer valid: this member function shall be called once at most for every future shared state.

And under **Exception safety**:

> The function throws the exception stored in the shared state when the provider makes it ready by setting it to an exception. Note that in this case a basic guarantee is offered, with the future object being modified to no longer be a valid future (which is itself a valid state for object of this type, despite its name).

Neither description makes a distinction between a call to `get` which returns a value versus one that throws an exception regarding the invalidation of the future object.

However, the described behavior is not what I'm seeing with this example code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>


int foo()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("foo exception");
}


int main()
{
    std::future<int> futInt;

    futInt = std::async(std::launch::async, []() { return foo(); });

    while( !(futInt.valid() && futInt.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready) )
        ;

    if( futInt.valid() )
    {
        int val;
        try
        {
            val = futInt.get();
        }
        catch( const std::exception& e )
        {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    if( futInt.valid() )
    {
        std::cout << "This is TOTALLY UNEXPECTED!!!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "This is expected." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output I see is:

```
foo exception
This is TOTALLY UNEXPECTED!!!
```

I'm using Visual Studio Premium 2013, Version 12.0.30501.00 Update 2. Is this a bug with the compiler or, in fact, correct behavior in the case of an exception? I've been unable to find any bug reports concerning this, so wasn't sure if it was expected behavior.

**Edit - <future> implementation investigation**

Digging into the `std::future` implementation a bit, the `_Associated_state` object is marked `_Retrieved = true;` **AFTER** checking and throwing the associated exception (if any):

```
virtual _Ty& _Get_value(bool _Get_only_once)
    {   // return the stored result or throw stored exception
    unique_lock<mutex> _Lock(_Mtx);
    if (_Get_only_once && _Retrieved)
        _Throw_future_error(
            make_error_code(future_errc::future_already_retrieved));
    if (_Exception)
        _Rethrow_future_exception(_Exception);
    _Retrieved = true;
    _Maybe_run_deferred_function(_Lock);
    while (!_Ready)
        _Cond.wait(_Lock);
    if (_Exception)
        _Rethrow_future_exception(_Exception);
    return (_Result);
    }
```

My guess is that the exception check and `_Retrieved = true;` should be swapped - the object should immediately be set as retrieved (after the `_Get_only_once` check) and then all other logic should follow. Ergo, compiler bug.

**Edit - workaround**

I think the following should suffice in lieu of directly calling `get` until a fix is implemented:

```
template<typename T>
T getFromFuture(std::future<T>& fut)
{
    try
    {
        return fut.get();
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        fut = {};
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: after printing `"This is TOTALLY UNEXPECTED!!!"`, what happens if you `futInt.get()` again?

Comment: g++ 4.8.4 gives "foo exception" and "This is expected."

Comment: @YSC - the "foo exception" gets thrown again (I tested this by copying the insides of the first if-statement immediately after the cout).

Comment: @DieterLücking - I _think_ yours is the expected behavior(?) This most likely is a compiler bug then, no?

Comment: I also suspect compiler issue. Could it be that the optimizer removes the first block as you don't ever use val ? What compiler options do you use? What if you move `int val` assigned to zero, to the beginning of main(), and then print it in the end?

Comment: @JohanLundberg - I don't think it's an optimization issue. The example code is a stripped down version of something more complex, but using the same type of structure.
I tried your suggestion, though, and it simply prints '0' for val (after the output I listed above).

Comment: `fut = {};` should work just fine for clearing it.

Comment: @T.C. - Thanks. I updated the workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compiled on Linux with gcc 5.2.0 and clang 3.7.0 -- both times with 64 Bit.
Running the program always results in

```
foo exception
This is expected.
```

It looks to me like Visual 2013 handles this incorrectly.
See also:

**C++ §30.6.6/16-17**

> *Throws:* the stored exception, if an exception was stored in the shared state.
>
> *Postcondition:* `valid() == false`.

The postcondition is mentioned after the throws and thus has to always hold, even if an exception is thrown. At least that is my interpretation, though I do not speak standardese.

I guess you should probably try also with Visual Studio 2015 and report a bug if that shows the same handling.

Comment: Confirmed same misbehavior in VS 2015 as well.
Thanks for the Standard reference.

Comment: apple clang7.0 with libc++ also well behaved.

Comment: VS 2017 gives
```foo exception
This is expected.```
So it seems to have been fixed